# Remove read-only permissions using Windows IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions, iis-7

I created a website in IIS (Internet Information Services Manager).

The directory, and files within this website, default to read-only permissions.

How can I remove the read-only permissions from these sites?

I tried:

- Deleting the folder, then recreating it
- Unchecking the read-only permissions in advanced settings (it resets itself automatically to read only.)
- Running IIS Manager as 'Administrator' account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are so few permissions problems that aren't annoying...

I can only give you advice from [a Google search](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=iis+stays+read+only&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) (it appears you're not the only one who's had this problem) that's probably unhelpful, like:

- try changing the folder permissions to read only via the command line e.g. `attrib +R FolderName`.
- look on the Security tab in the Properties window and see what the exact permissions are there, for your logged in user or any of the groups you're in. See if they're set appropriately, and try changing them from there.
- restart machine

I just hope I haven't enraged you more when this advice doesn't work.

Comment: Not at all , perfectly sound advice, it seems that flag is always set on any folder.

Answer (score 6):

This is "by design" according to Microsoft. See "[You cannot view or change the Read-only or the System attributes of folders in Windows Server 2003, in Windows XP, or in Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;326549)".

Excerpt:

> Unlike the Read-only attribute for a file, the Read-only attribute for a folder is typically ignored by Windows, Windows components and accessories, and other programs. For example, you can delete, rename, and change a folder with the Read-only attribute by using Windows Explorer. The Read-only and System attributes is only used by Windows Explorer to determine whether the folder is a special folder, such as a system folder that has its view customized by Windows (for example, My Documents, Favorites, Fonts, Downloaded Program Files), or a folder that you customized by using the Customize tab of the folder's Properties dialog box. As a result, Windows Explorer does not allow you to view or change the Read-only or System attributes of folders.

See link for full details.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, change the security settings for the user IIS_IUSRS to full control. The read-only box will still be ticked (most likely because the CREATOR OWNER cannot be granted full control) but the IIS processes will be able to write files to the target directory. I agree this is an annoying problem because the code will work in Cassini but not on the server.